# How loop through an array, add only string's that start with 'a' to a new array?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is what was given for the question. I understand how to loop through an array. I do not know how to check a specific character in each string in the array and then how to copy those string's to a new array?

Question: Loop through the famous array add only people whose names start with 'a' to your favorites:

```
var favorites = [];

  var famous = [ 'alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt',
  'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis'];
```

My answer so far:

```
  var favoriteLetter = 'a';
  for(var i = 0; i < famous.length; i++) {
    if(famous.indexOf(0) === favoriteLetter) {
      favorites.push(famous[i]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: the simple way: `favorites=famous.filter(/./.test, /^a/i)`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 if(famous.indexOf(0) === favoriteLetter)
```

to

```
 if(famous[i].charAt(0) === favoriteLetter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `.indexOf(0)` is incorrect.  Instead, you want `.charAt(0)` on each individual string in the array.  So, change this:

```
if(famous.indexOf(0) === favoriteLetter) {
```

to this:

```
 if(famous[i].charAt(0) === favoriteLetter) {
```

---

Here's some fixed up code in a working snippet:

```js
var famous = [ 'alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis'];
var favorites = [];
var favoriteLetter = 'a';
for(var i = 0; i < famous.length; i++) {
     if(famous[i].charAt(0) === favoriteLetter) {
         favorites.push(famous[i]);
     }
}

 document.write(JSON.stringify(favorites));
```

You may find it a little cleaner to use `.filter()`.

```js
var famous = [ 'alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis'];
var favoriteLetter = 'a';
var favorites = famous.filter(function(item) {
    return item.charAt(0) === favoriteLetter;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(favorites));
```

Comment: you forgot  to put index on famous.

Comment: Added second example that uses `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is great. Just to throw another one out there, you can also take the "functional programming" route using the `_.filter()` method implemented by [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), etc. (also [native ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in modern browsers and IE9+).

```
var favoriteLetter = 'a',
    favorites = _.filter(famous, function(name) {
      return name.charAt(0) === favoriteLetter;
    }));
```

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpXQvv?editors=001).